# Windows system partition has 450 GB free but cannot be shrunk

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I have bought a laptop with a 1 TB bitlocker encrypted drive and Windows 10 installed. I want o reduce the Windows C partition from under 1TB to ~200 GB. I was able to reduce it by ca 476 GB. Now it still has more than 450 GB free but cannot be shrunk anymore.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely has the NTFS MFT in the middle (of the original 1 TB). The MFT can only be moved when the partition is dismounted (i.e. NTFS is not actively using it), which you can't do when it's the OS volume.

Reboot into a Windows install USB stick (any recent version will do), hit Shift+F10 for the console window, then use `manage-bde` to unlock the BitLocker volume (will need the recovery key) and `diskpart` to shrink the partition to the size you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with a linux usb and gparted first

Comment: @cipricus The same should be able to be done from WinRE, simply dismount the OS partition via `diskpart`

Comment: Trying with Linux live session I cannot resize either because it's locked (I guess): it appears as "bitlocker" type partition. The laptop was bough t as such - second hand - I haven't locked the drive myself and I don't have a recovery key. Or is it stored somewhere on the recovery partition maybe?

Comment: Reboot into your normal system, run `manage-bde -protectors C: -get`, then write it down. (There's also an option to save/print it from BitLocker GUI.)